# Spring Cloud Stream with Avro cannot correctly convert String message

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I got a problem that source sends a GenericMessage [payload=xxxxx, ...] while sink receives the message as 10,120,120,120,120,120.

This problem happened after I had set up Avro message converters. If I remove Avro message converters and use StreamListener to handle message conversion, it will work fine.

Source application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.toGreeting.destination=greeting
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.toGreeting.contentType=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled=true
```

Sink application

```
server.port=8990 
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.greeting.destination=greeting
```

Message Converter

```
@Configuration
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class MessageConverterConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter topic1MessageConverter() throws IOException {
        return new AvroSchemaMessageConverter(MimeType.valueOf("avro/bytes"));
    }
}
```

Application Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class SourceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SourceApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@EnableSchemaRegistryServer
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class SinkApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SinkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Am I missing configurations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple rule:

If you only want to have a message converter that can serialize/deserialize from avro, and you either provide the schema location during configuration for GenericRecords or your StreamListener method has a signature of a type of SpecificRecord. Then choose `AvroSchemaMessageConverter`, set it up like you did, but use `avro/bytes` instead. We reserve the `application/*+avro` for schema evolution support.

So, if you set `@EnableSchemaRegistryClient` then you are delegating to an external registry to have your schemas. In that case, not only you need the registry but also the schemas registered there.

By default producers will automatically register any payload of type SpecificRecord/GenericRecord or Pojos if `spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled` is enabled.

In that case, the producer will actually set the header to something like `application/vnd.user.v1+avro` Assuming your subject is User and it's the first version.

Downstream, if your consumers are also configured with `application/*+avro` contentType, they will be able to read this contentType and infer it's subject/version for querying the schema server and retrieve the appropriate schema.

Comment: Vinicius can you please have a look at my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548365/spring-cloud-schema-registry-client-does-not-convert-to-avro-and-i-get-org-sprin

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.toGreeting.contentType=application/*+avro` then the `AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter` (which gets configured by SCSt) needs to be used and you don't have to set the `explicit` converter `topic1MessageConverter` for the MimeType `avro/bytes`.

If you want to make use of this converter, then you would need to set `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.toGreeting.contentType=avro/bytes`.

Comment: I am running a ```@SpringBootTest``` with a configuration that includes ```AvroSchemaMessageConverter``` configured as described here, but my test is failing in ```MessageConverterConfigurer.doPresend(Message<?>, MessageChannel)``` when the messageConverter tries to convert the message. In my case, the messageConverter is an instance of ```CompositeMessageConverter```, and I don't see my ```AvroSchemaMessageConverter``` in its list of converters. Any ideas about why this converter isn't being registered?

Comment: @KeithBennett I have exactly the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @CarlosCuesta Yes, I ended up implementing the following:

```@Bean
   @ConditionalOnProperty("com.acme.avro-schema-message-converter.enabled", havingValue = "true")
   public MessageConverter avroSchemaMessageConverter() {
     return new AvroSchemaMessageConverter(MimeType.valueOf("avro/bytes"),
       new AvroSchemaServiceManagerImpl());
   }
```

Then, in your ```src/test/resources/bootstrap.yml```, just be sure you set this property to true.

Comment: @CarlosCuesta I also have the following class defined for my microservice (the previous comment is for the bean to be used in your tests).

```@Configuration
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "com.acme.schema-registry-client.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class SchemaRegistryClientConfiguration {}```

Of course, be sure to set this property to true in application.yml.

Comment: With the ```@Bean``` and ```@Configuration``` defined via the previous two comments and their corresponding properties set, I'm able to utilize the Spring Cloud Schema Registry in prod and run ```@SpringBootTest```s during my Maven builds where I can send messages via ```SubscribableChannel```s and utilize Spring's great testing facilities. Hope this helps you!

Comment: After adding the bean you meantioned to the @Configuration, I got this: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'avroSchemaMessageConverter'....There is already defined in class path resource [com/project/subproject/AvroConfig.class]] bound. Can anyone help?